# Style a html table inside functions.php wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, wordpress

I have created a function on `functions.php` file that retrieves data from a table in our database and places it inside an `HTML`.

My problem is that I need to style this table, its columns and rows in order to set the margins, padding, etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
add_shortcode( 'persona-table', 'persona_table_shortcode' );

// this function generates the shortcode output
function persona_table_shortcode( $args ) {
    global $wpdb;
    // Shortcodes RETURN content, so store in a variable to return
    $content = '<table class="tabledatos">';
        $content .= '<tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Points</th></tr>';
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM persona' );
        foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
            $content = '<tr>';
                // Modify these to match the database structure
                $content .= '<td class=rowtable>' . $row->ID_per . '</td>';
                $content .= '<td class=rowtable>' . $row->nombre . '</td>';
                $content .= '<td class=rowtable>' . $row->apellido . '</td>';
                $content .= '<td class=rowtable>' . $row->documento . '</td>';
                $content .= '<td class=rowtable>' . $row->tel. '</td>';
            $content .= '<tr>';
        }
    $content .= '</table>';
    // return the table
    return $content;
}
```

As you can see on every `<td>` I have added a class called `rowtable`, but when I refresh the page the table does not take the style defined on that class. Also, I tried to use quotes as you can see on the class `tabledatos` for the whole table, nevertheless this is not working.

How can I add classes to this code so that I can customize them on the `style.css` file?

Comment: Are you sure you have `rowtable` class? Any clues in developers console?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not coming with the full answer to your question (sadly) and I'm not that good with `PHP`, but maybe I can help you to find this answer.

First of all, have you checked (using your browser's tools) if the `CSS` file was included on your page and if your table has the class? If you haven't, you should check it now. If the table doesn't have this class, try adding it manually (with the browser's tools) and see if the table is updated.

If this first step hasn't worked, there is another way to add class to your object. You could add a class to your object with `JavaScript` by using the member function `.addClass("tabledatos");`

Hope you'll find something interesting in my comment

Answer (score 0):

First of all HTML attributes with content always require quotes so your rows should look something like this: `$content .= '<td class="rowtable">' . $row->ID_per . '</td>';`

Than you should verify that your stylesheet is loaded as supposed and check in the dev tools of you browser if the class is added to the `td`.

And here `$content = '<tr>';` you reassign your variable that means your previous content get flushed and that for every item in your foreach